# Polynomial with integer coefficients ($f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$) with odd $ad$ and even $bc$ implies not all rational roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, proof-verification

Today, I attempted this problem in the ISI admission test for B.Math UG2016 for which I want my solution to be verified (whether it is correct or not)

**Q:** Given $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ where $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb Z$ and $ad$ is odd and $bc$ is even. Prove that $f(x)$ cannot have all rational roots.

**My attempted solution:**

Let us assume that there are three rational roots of $f(x)$, namely $\dfrac{p_1}{q_1},\dfrac{p_2}{q_2}$ and $\dfrac{p_3}{q_3}$ where we have WLOG $q_1,q_2,q_3\gt 0$ and $\gcd(p_i,q_i)=1~\forall~1\leq i\leq 3$

Now, by Vieta's formulas, we have,

$$\frac{p_1}{q_1}+\frac{p_2}{q_2}+\frac{p_3}{q_3}=-\frac ba\implies a(p_1q_2q_3+p_2q_3q_1+p_3q_1q_2)=-bq_1q_2q_3\tag1$$

$$\frac{p_1p_2}{q_1q_2}+\frac{p_2p_3}{q_2q_3}+\frac{p_2p_2}{q_1q_2}=\frac ca\implies a(p_1p_2q_3+p_2p_3q_1+p_3p_1q_2)=cq_1q_2q_3\tag2$$

Now, since $ad$ is odd, both $a,d$ must be odd and since $bc$ is even, either $b$ or $c$ is even.

By the rational root theorem and since both $a,d$ are odd, we know that all the $p_i$'s and $q_i$'s are odd and hence any product involving the $p_i$'s and the $q_i$'s will be odd.

If $b$ is even, we consider $(1)$ for which the LHS is odd $\times$ odd $=$ odd and the RHS is even $\times$ odd $=$ even which is a contradiction since LHS and RHS cannot have different parity.

If $c$ is even, we consider $(2)$ and use a similar argument to show that the parity of the LHS and the RHS is different which is a contradiction.

Hence, in both cases, we arrive at a contradiction and hence our assumption that $f(x)$ has all rational roots was wrong.

Therefore, $f(x)$ cannot have all rational roots.

---

Is my solution correct? Also, I think I forgot to show for both the cases of $b$ and $c$ being even like I did here (due to rush of the exam hour). I probably just showed for the case of $b$ being even. If such a solution is to be graded out of $10$ for correctness, how much might it be graded  if it just shows one of the cases?

Comment: A question (not related to this). Do most people who give this exam opt for B.Maths or B.Stats?  (P.S. I also gave this exam today, that's why I'd like to know.)

Comment: I think this looks good.

Comment: Minor comment, without real loss of generality we may assume $b$ is even, for if $b$ is odd and $c$ is even, we can consider the "backwards" equation (let $x=1/t$).

Comment: @Gummybears, Yeah, this exam is only for B.Math/B.Stat admission in ISI (you can opt for any one of them but not both).

Comment: @AndréNicolas, ah, that's a good point. But if I don't give this justification (that we can take WLOG $b$ as even) and just prove for the case of even $b$, how much would it be graded on a scale of 1-10 in your opinion?

Comment: @idiot I know that. I wanted to ask whether more people opt for Maths or for Stats.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is fine. You could also argue that with roots $\frac {p_i}{q_i}$ in lowest terms $f(x)=n(q_1x-p_1)(q_2x-p_2)(q_3x-p_3)$ for some integer $n$.

The oddness of $ad$ makes $n, p_i, q_i$ all odd, and $b,c$ are then each the sum of three odd numbers (therefore are odd).

Alternatively, take the factorisation modulo $2$, which becomes $(x+1)^3\equiv x^3+x^2+x+1$ and again shows that all the coefficients must be odd.